# ¿Cómo puedo conectarme a una base de datos remota desde un docker-compose local?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, docker, docker-compose

Tengo un **docker-compose.yml** con tres contenedores(mysql, wordpress y phpmyadmin) y lo que necesito es conectar wordpress a mi base de datos remota que tengo en un servicio de hosting.

¿Como puedo hacer para trabajar con wordpress y mi base de datos local, pero cuando ya tenga todo preparado entonces cambiar a mi base de datos remota todo usando mi archivo de **docker-compose.yml**?

Éste es mi **docker-compose.yml**

```
  version: '3'

  services:
    db:
      container_name: mysql-example
      image: mysql:latest
      command:
            - "--character-set-server=utf8"
            - "--collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci"
      volumes: 
        - $PWD/data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment: 
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
        MYSQL_USER: wordpress
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      restart: always
      networks:
        - my_net

    wordpress:
      container_name: wordpress
      volumes:
        - "$PWD/html:/var/www/html"
        - "$PWD/html/themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes"
        - "$PWD/html/plugins:/var/www.html/wp-content/plugins"
        - "$PWD/html/uploads:/var/www.html/wp-content/uploads"
      depends_on:
        - db
      image: wordpress:latest
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      restart: always
      environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
        WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      networks:
        - my_net

    phpmyadmin:
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      ports: 
        - 8080:80
      restart: always
      environment: 
        PMA_HOST: db
      depends_on:
        - db
      networks:
        - my_net
        
  networks:
    my_net:
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo ideal es que los entornos sean idénticos, en este caso lo mas conveniente, en mi opinión, sería que quitaras la base de datos del docker-compose.yml, puedes hacerla localmente con otro docker, al cambiar de entorno, cambiarías las variables de conexion, passwords etc. de la base de datos local por la remota.

Comment: Probablemente tengas que hablar con tu servicio de hosting para que admitan conexiones externas a tu servidor de BBDD. Normalmente está capado por motivos de seguridad.